# Best practice for printing in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, printing

I'm looking to print my view to an A5-printer but when I test the print functionality to pdf, I always get a narrow and long printout.

Is there a way to set the pageheight and width? According to adobe help it's read-only.

Does anyone have experience with printing in flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default flex printing is indeed rather dodgy.

If you really want smoother printouts, you could use one of the following open source libraries that do the job just fine

- On the client side:
  [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/)
  or [PurePDF (as3 IText Port)](http://blog.sephiroth.it/projects/purepdf/)
- On the server side (through BlazeDS or a servlet): [IText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Cheers

Comment: I would advice AlivePDF. (Very easy to work with)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:
http://www.kalengibbons.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/custom-printing-with-flex-part-3-printing-data/

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on full solution flex printing (+ preview) and PDF generation that i think will be very helpful, check it out at http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/